# Git remember password for a few minutes?

Tags: git, passwords, credentials

When I want to merge my updates from development to production I am naturally running multiple `git pull` and `git push` commands to get the job done. For every single one of those commands Git will ask me for my password. (You may ask why I have to do multiple pull/push, well, just to make sure I include everything in case someone else pushed to my branch or production branch before me).

I want to avoid entering my password four times, I know there is a non-secure method to store credentials with Git, but that's not what I ask. What I ask is to enter my password just once and "magically" expect Git to remember it for a few seconds before it asks me again. Is there a built-in support for this or I have to do something on my own?

UPDATE:
Quoting from my comment below :

> I have tried `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=300'` and now if I run `git config --global --edit` I can see my config file having this line under `[credential]` : `helper = cache --timeout=300`. However, I try a dummy command `git pull`, enter password and `git pull` again, but I am asked for password again.

Any idea what is wrong ? My git version is 1.9.1 and I saw that the credential.helper is introduced in an earlier version.

Comment: What version of git are you using? In recent versions the [credential manager](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) will automatically cache your credentials so you won't be continuously prompted.

Comment: I am using 1.9.1. Interesting, is it a good idea to udate to 2.10 ? Are there many differences in the interface ?

Comment: For the most part it works the same way `clone`, `push`, `pull`, `commit`, etc just as you'd expect. There are a few interface changes too summarized [here](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/git-v2-0-0/) and [here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/06/happened-git-2-0-full-goodies/).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=300'` and now if I run `git config --global --edit` I can see my config file having this line under [credential] : `helper = cache --timeout=300`. However, I try a dummy command `git pull`, enter password and `git pull` again, but I am asked for password again. This is weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)